# Is there a way to rename a cloudformation stack name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a cloudformation stack (which is generated from stack_master), Resources are already created but I would like to put it into serverless framework. I have already added the **resources** section but It creates new stack. I want the stack to update existing stack and any updates to take from there.
Thanks

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 15):

Its **not possible** to rename a stack. You have to delete it, and create new one with the name you want.

Answer (score 5):

No longer the case as of 2022 - it looks as though you can retain stack resources whilst deleting the stack containing then, and import those resources into a new stack tldr; I have not done this, just reading the docs https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/keep-your-aws-resources-when-you-rename-an-aws-cloudformation-stack/

Comment: Be really nice if someone wrote a tool that would do this.

Comment: @CodySwann There is https://github.com/iann0036/cfn-stack-rename although I have not tried using it at all, so caveat emptor etc.

Comment: I would call it a workaround

Answer (score 1):

> For most resources, changing the logical name of a resource is
> equivalent to deleting that resource and replacing it with a new one.
> Any other resources that depend on the renamed resource also need to
> be updated and might cause to be replaced. Other resources require you
> to update a property (not just the logical name) in order to initiate
> an update.

So Logically you have to delete the stack and create a new one as you want.

You can check out this link: [AWS Official Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-get-template.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note
AWS CloudFormation only supports one level of nesting using resource import. This means that you can't import a stack into a child stack or import a stack that has children.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html